# How to keep an application open even after a user logs off and back on in RedHat 8.2 Linux?

Tags: linux, redhat

I am looking for a way to keep an application (not a script) open in Red Hat Linux 8.2 when multiple users are logging on and off on the same machine. So if user A in one user group uses an application, logs off, I want that application to still be open when user B logs on. Is this possible? I tried looking at the GDM (GNOME display manager) for RedHat but wasn't able to make much of it.

I've tried the following [methods](https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/), but none seem to work.

Thank you

Comment: This question seems off-topic here since SO is more about programming. I guess you will get better results if you move your question to [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You Can detach your session
tmux detach
And to attach to your session
tmux a -t SESSION_NAME

Comment: Please, spend some time reading ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately screen is [unavailable for RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4136481) 8.0.0 and newer.

Comment: Did you try tmux multitasking linux application it used to keep a process working in the background

Comment: I did, yes. When I launch the application I am using to test, I log out, log back in, and the application is closed plus the tmux session doesn't exist anymore.